# Как вытащить немного информации с другого сайта?

Tags: php, get

Нужен способ -

Допустим ссылка http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=90927

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать чтобы скрипт вытаскивал из этой странички цену 1 и выводил её?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в вашем случае необходимо делать гетом запрос на 
http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=90927&xhr=1 где **code** - код товара
жду плюсик :D

Comment: Сложность тут вся немного больше чем на первый взгляд... Дело в том, что в исходном коде страницы необходимые данные не были обнаружены (Сам в шоке)

Comment: Вахех)) Спасиииб)) Расскажи откуда взял этот xhr??

Comment: firebug + опыт :)

Comment: Блин) А как дальше вытаскивать?

Comment: а дальше регулярками :) за спасибо не сделаю т.к. не 5 минут...

Comment: просто слово "регулярками" не очень понятно... можно пример ?

Comment: Нашёл мануал) Спасибо

Comment: незачто, дерзайте :)